# I want to change image when its flipping Animation android

Tags: android

It is possible to make keep changing image until it set final image.

i want to change image while its flipping.
so it look smooth while flipping

```
private ImageView image;
 private void images() {

    int[] ps={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2};
    Random r = new Random();
    int n=r.nextInt(2);
    image.setImageResource(ps[n]);

    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(coin, "rotationY", 0f, 360f);
    animation.setDuration(500);
    animation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());
    animation.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can do this for that you should use Flip animation, you can find code for this from [Here](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html) 
create XML file in `res/animator` with help of above link

than in java file

```
ObjectAnimator anim = (ObjectAnimator)
AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(mContext, R.animator.[FILE NAME]); 

int[] ps={R.drawable.img1,R.drawable.img2};
Random r = new Random();
int n=r.nextInt(2);
image.setImageResource(ps[n]);

anim.setTarget(image);
anim.setDuration(500);
anim.start();
```